# How to drag and drop a picture from a home folder into an open application in full size?

Tags: unity

how to drag and drop a picture from a home folder into an open application in full size? I wanted to take a picture file (CD cover) and drag-and-drop it to Rhythmbox for a selected song/album. Not sure how to do that in Unity. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean an application that is maximized?

Comment: I have always envied [this feature](http://www.betalogue.com/2009/07/14/command-tab/) of Mac OS X. I periodically try it in Ubuntu, with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question 100%, but here's trying :-)

So, consider you have Eye of Gnome opened somewhere (maximized or not) and you have a maximized Nautilus (the file manager) window open and you have found a picture in there you want to see in EOG. In this situation it is normally impossible to drag the file outside the maximized file manager window - I guess this is your problem?

If it is, then here's the solution: Drag the image out of the file manager over the launcher (the application bar on the left side of the screen). Now all applications that can open the particulat file type you are dragging should light up (all others will dim out). Then just drop the image file on top of the shining EOG tile.

In the case of Rhythmbox you mention there may be a slight problem. From my tests it doesn't light up, meaning that it's not registered as being able to open PNG files (which is what I am dragging). You can easily fix this, though. Just do:

```
sudo nano -w /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop
```

Find the line that starts with `MimeType=` and append to the end of that line `image/jpeg;image/png;` so it looks like:

```
MimeType=application/x-ogg;application/ogg;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-flac;image/jpeg;image/png;
```

Then hit Control-X to exit the editor and remember to choose "save" when it asks you.

Now restart Rhythmbox and the dragging exercise from above again, maybe hovering over the launcher for a while until the Rhythmbox window pops up, then move over that window until it goes fullscreen and drop the image in the artwork zone.

Good luck!